# Parsed strings from .csv-file are invalid tokens in an kml-file. How can i solve this?

Tags: java, csv

I have a code which parses strings from an CSV.-file (with twitter data) and gives them to a new KML file. When i parse the comments from the twitter data there are of course unknown tokens like: ðŸš¨. When i open up the new KML-File in Google Earth i get an error because of this unknown tokens.
Question:
When i parse the strings, can i tell java it should throw out all unknown tokens from the string so that i don't have any unknown tokens in my KML?

Thank you

Code below:

```
String csvFile = "twitter.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ";";
    String[] twitter = null;
    int row_desired = 0;
    int row_counter = 0;
    String[] placemarks = new String[1165];
    // ab hier einlesen der CSV
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (row_counter++ == row_desired) {
                twitter = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                placemarks[row_counter] = 
                        "<Placemark>\n"+
                        "<name>User ID: "+twitter[7]+"</name>\n"+
                        "<description>This User wrote: "+twitter[5]+" at the: "+twitter[6]+"</description>\n"+
                        "<Point>\n"+
                        "<coordinates>"+twitter[1]+","+twitter[2]+"</coordinates>\n"+
                        "</Point>\n"+
                        "</Placemark>\n";
                row_desired++;
            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= 1164;i++){

    String kml2 = kml.concat(""+placemarks[i]+"");
    kml=kml2;
    }
    kml = kml.concat("</Document></kml>");

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filepath);
    fileWriter.write(kml);
    fileWriter.close();

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(googlefilepath + filepath);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text files are not all built equal: you must always consider what character encoding is in use. I'm not sure about Twitter's data specifically, but I would guess they're doing like the rest of the world and using UTF-8.

Basically, avoid `FileReader` and instead use the constructor of `InputStreamReader` which lets you specify the Charset.

Tip: if you're using Java 7+, try this:

```
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) { ...
```

**More Info**

The javadoc of `FileReader` states "The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding"

You should avoid this class, always. Or at least for any data that might ever be transferred between computers. Even a program running on Windows "using the default charset" will assume UTF-8 when run from inside Eclipse, or ISO_8859_1 when running outside Eclipse! Such non-determinism from a class is not good.

Comment: Oh and use a CSV library, such as OpenCSV. Even with this simple format things get tricky with: some fields quoted and some not, double-quote escape sequence, and fields containing new-line characters.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There were "&" chars in the comments which are operators in XML and caused the parsing error. So it was not a problem with the encoding. But i will use inputstreamreader now, you convinced me ;).

Comment: OK, glad you've got that sorted!